# Home-brew install both OpenCV 2.4 and OpenCV3.1 on a Mac?

Tags: python, c++, macos, opencv, homebrew

I have OpenCV3.1 installed with Homebrew on my Mac, but for a new project I need to use OpenCV2.4. I just checked with the following commands:

```
$brew info opencv3
$brew info opencv
```

Seems to me that two versions of OpenCV are independent.

So my question is if I can install OpenCV2.4 without causing interference to my OpenCV 3.1? Also like to know if I can use either Python or C++ to call OpenCV if both two versions are installed?

Thanks for your suggestions and comments

Answer (score 2):

Was asking myself the same question today...

For me the following worked so far:
Using homebrew and pyenv (the latter I installed with homebrew), 
I decided to use python3 with opencv3 and python2.7 with opencv2 (both anaconda-python distributions). To have the python installations as clean as possible, do not use homebrew to install python or packages but pyenv. Also during the opencv installation the `--without-numpy` is important.
The rough steps are:

1. use pyenv to set the global python
2. install opencv
3. use conda to install the python packages
4. manually link the opencv-python packages to the active python distribution

The commands for opencv2 then look like:

```
pyenv global anaconda-2.4.0
brew install opencv --with-ffmpeg --with-java --without-numpy
conda install -c "https://conda.binstar.org/menpo opencv"
echo "/usr/local/opt/opencv/lib/python2.7/site-packages" >> "~/.pyenv/versions/anaconda-2.4.0/lib/python2.7/site-packages/homebrew-opencv.pth"
```

For opencv3 the main difference is in the options when installing the formula:

```
brew install opencv3 --without-numpy --with-python3 --with-contrib --with-examples --with--ffmpeg --with-java
```

The rest can be adapted one to one from the opencv2 code. To get the paths right `brew info opencv` helps.

Comment: Nicely documented !(+1) I installed OpenCV3 alongside OpenCV2 (ignoring Python) using [this blog post](http://www.learnopencv.com/install-opencv-3-on-yosemite-osx-10-10-x/). FWIW, I mainly use Python 2.7 mostly, but when I need to use Python 3 I setup a [virtualenv](docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/dev/virtualenvs/)

Comment: the way the paths from opencv are added to python, the here documented way allows only for one opencv version (both opencv2 and opencv3 are imported with `import cv2`, which provoques conflicts). Switching between versions would need a change of the homebrew-opencv.path file. So indeed, if both versions of opencv should work in python2.7 virtual environments is the only way I can think of too.